# how to manage gridview column when row text is too long in c# asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am using ASP.net (C#) 3.5

In my gidview, there are 3 columns Name, Email and Password.

Email can not be more than 25 character string.
Password is always shown as 6 '*'s
but in the name column, (it can be 200 character string), if it is more than 50, or 60 characters, my gridview design is demolished. i want to split the string and make it on another line. means if string is long enough it will contain two line or three in the same row.

Please help how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Wrap property

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>

</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="80px" Wrap="true" /> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: there is only 
<TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>

where should i add wrap property?